# Is $U^\dagger(R)\hat{H}U(R)=\hat{H}$ always true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, rotation, unitarity

Consider a Rotation transformation on momentum state,
$$U^\dagger(R)\hat{\mathbf{p}}U(R)=R\hat{\mathbf{p}}$$

Now the question is whether,

$$U^\dagger(R)\hat{H}U(R)=\hat{H}\,?$$

Here, $\hat{H}$ is the Hamiltonian of a free particle. Is it always true? Is there any counter examples?

My attempt:
\begin{align}
U^\dagger(R)\hat{H}U(R)&=\frac{1}{2m}U^\dagger(R)\hat{\mathbf{p}}^2U(R)\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}U^\dagger(R)\hat{\mathbf{p}}U(R)U^\dagger(R)\hat{\mathbf{p}}U(R)\\
&=\frac{1}{2m}(R\hat{\mathbf{p}})(R\hat{\mathbf{p}})
\end{align}
Is this always true that $$\frac{1}{2m}(R\hat{\mathbf{p}})(R\hat{\mathbf{p}})=\frac{1}{2m}\hat{\mathbf{p}}^2\, ?$$

If it is why? If not when it is not?

Note: This is an exercise from Coleman's course 253a (https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013). See equation (1.8) there. It would be better if the answer is provided using his notations.

Comment: Please fill in the details, define the notation you are using, add context and details as to make the question more precise. Additionally this seems just to ask whether the Hamiltonian is always rotational symmetric. The answer is obviously no, not all systems have spherical symmetry.

Comment: @ohneVal Thanks for the suggestion. I've added some details now. Do you think it is sufficient?

Comment: Well $R \vec{a} \cdot R \vec{a} = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}$  for all vectors $\vec{a}$ (rotations conserve length), including $\vec{a}$ having components as operators like $\vec{p}$ .

Comment: This is true so long as the Hamiltonian is rotationally invariant. You're just asking if $U(R)$ commutes with $\hat{H}$. If you had a free electron in a background B field for instance, the interaction between the field and the magnetic moment would break rotational invariance.

Answer (score 1):

It is true in this specific case that, if $\hat H=\frac{1}{2m}\mathbf{p}^2$ is the Hamiltonian for the free particle, then $U^\dagger\hat{\mathbf{p}}^2 U=\hat{\mathbf{p}}^2$ for $U$ a rotation.

Maybe the 2d case is sufficient to illustrate the point.  We have
\begin{align}
R^\dagger_z(\theta)\hat{p}_xR(\theta)&=\hat{p}_x^\prime=\hat{p}_x\cos\theta+\hat{p}_y\sin\theta\, ,\\
R^\dagger_z(\theta)\hat{p}_yR(\theta)&= \hat{p}_y^\prime=-\hat{p}_x\sin\theta +\hat{p}_y\cos\theta
\end{align}
and then
\begin{align}
\mathbf{p^\prime}^2=\mathbf{p}^2\, .
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
{\hat{p}_x^\prime}^2=\hat{p}_x^2+\hat{p}_y^2 +\hat{p}_x\hat{p}_y
+\hat{p}_y\hat{p}_x
\end{align}
keeping the ordering straight but since $\hat{p}_x$ and $\hat{p}_y$ commute then it boils down to the usual $\hat{p}_x\hat{p}_y+\hat{p}_y\hat{p}_x=2\hat{p}_x\hat{p}_y$.

Answer (score 0):

If the operator $U$ is indeed the unitary operator, then

$U U^{\dagger}= U^{\dagger} U = 1$

then expression you have (which appears to be applied incorrectly) above will reduce back to its original form

$\frac{1}{2m} U^{\dagger} p^2 U = U^{\dagger} H U = H$

Comment: What is incorrect? I don't get it. Can you please elaborate? In any case, forget about my attempt and can you prove expression (1.8) in Coleman's lecture note?

Comment: Let me have a read of it and I’ll come back to you.

Comment: That equation you refer to is the unitary rotation operator transformation of H and because of its properties it is very trivial to prove that equation. Have a shot at it - it will be a good exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Base transformations of a scalar operator (H) and the vector operator's spatial rotation are confused here, I think. Try to rewrite it in bra-ket notation.

Coordinate -> momentum space transformations also done in $ UHU^{-1} $ way and it really changes H.

Comment: I'm only talking about vector operators $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$ and their rotation with respect to an unitary operator $U(R)$. There's no state here. I don't understand what do I have to write in bra-ket notation. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dot product in fact $\mathbf p^2 = \mathbf p^{\dagger} \mathbf p$. So one may do the following:
$$
U^{\dagger} \mathbf p^{\dagger} \mathbf p \  U = 
U^{\dagger} \mathbf p^{\dagger} U U^{\dagger} \mathbf p \  U = (U^{\dagger} \mathbf p \  U)^{\dagger} U^{\dagger} \mathbf p \  U = (R \mathbf p)^{\dagger} R \mathbf p = \mathbf p R^{\dagger} R \mathbf p = \mathbf p^{\dagger} \mathbf p
$$
Here I've denoted the transposed momentum $p^{\dagger}$ to unify notation, despite the fact, it is real, And in the last step, I've used, that the $R$-matrix is unitary.

Comment: This must be faulty as it implies $\mathbf{p}^2$ is proportional to the unit operator as it would commute with any unitary $U$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero you're right, I've forgot about the Schur's lemma